# Conditionals and overriding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using a conditional to check if two values exists. I want to override the first conditional with the second one. Most likely if the second one exists then the first will, if that makes sense. Not the issue i'm having is using two different call methods.

What I have so far:

```
<% @data.each do |i| %>
  <% if i.stock.present? %>
    In Stock
  <% elsif i.sold.present? %>
    Sold
  <% else %>
    n/a
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, if in stock display 'In Stock', if sold display 'Sold'.

Comment: This is why TDD is important. What outputs are you expecting in each of your example cases?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When you say "override the first conditional with the second one", I'm assuming your saying that `i.stock.present?` is always true? Is stock an integer? If so, calling `present?` on 0 will return `true`.

Comment: What I’m mean is, is that if the first condition is true, then the display the message in stock, but if the second condition is present, then instead display sold. If none are present then display nothing. But the first condition will always be there if the second is, and that’s the issue I’m having. At the moment if both are present it displays both in stock and sold messages.

Comment: "At the moment if both are present it displays both in stock and sold messages". Are you sure about that? Or, is it displaying both because you are looping through `@data`, which has items that are both in stock and sold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution, but feel free to let me know if there is a better way. This is using the unless statement and seems to display what I need.

```
<% @data.each do |i| %>
  <% unless i.stock.present? %>
    In Stock
  <% else if i.sold.present? %>
      Sold
    <% else %>
      n/a
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```